Randomly color the words
Inspired by this X post.
Write a program or function that takes a string as input and prints or otherwise renders the text with each word in a random color, e.g.:


The input will be a string of printable and whitespace ASCII characters.

For our purposes a word is a contiguous sequence of non-whitespace characters.

Whitespace characters are, at a minimum: Space, tab, and newline. (You may optionally count characters such as vertical tab, form feed, and carriage return—i.e. those in many regular expression engines' [[:space]] classes—as whitespace.) All whitespace characters must be preserved in the output.

Output may be colored text in any environment (such as a terminal or HTML page) or an image (see Rules).

At least 16 distinct colors must be possible. It is not a requirement that the possible colors be evenly distributed but it should be likely that various hues and shades are represented in the result.

The output must have a chance of being different each time the program or function is run with the same input.

Any background color is allowed.

Solutions must include a working demo or a screenshot of sample output.


Rules

Default I/O rules and standard rules apply. Standard loopholes are forbidden.

For image output default image I/O rules apply.

This is code-golf; shortest solution in bytes wins.



Sandbox

PETSCII okay though?

@ShaunBebbington Sure, go for it.

@emanresuA I have amended the question.

Now 3 answers output HTML, should have some test cases inputting HTML tags

Arturo, 73 bytes
$=>[loop match&{\S+|\s+}=>[prints color to :color map 3=>[255 1random]&]]

Try it!
Works in the online playground and most terminals.

C (gcc), 92 91 bytes
x;f(int*s){for(x=srand(s);*s;x=!s++)printf("\e[38;5;%dm%s",x|isspace(*s)?rand()%256:-1,s);}

Demo
-1 byte thanks to ceilingcat!

This is great, but it seems like it only counts spaces as whitespace, and it always colors the first sequence of non-spaces white: https://onlinegdb.com/uDg9s7MBy I'll edit the question to make the spec more clear on these points.

@Jordan I have updated my answer to address these issues.

Looks good! ~min. comment length...~

05AB1E, 33 31 29 28 26 bytes
.γð›}ε7Ý39Sδì˜Ω27ç"ÿ[ÿmÿ"?

-4 bytes thanks to @emanresu
Uses the 16 Windows 10 console colors.
Screenshot (which took a while to make, since apparently there was a Windows-10 patch that disabled ANSI again, so I had to enable it (again) in my Registry..):

Try it online (to see the actual ANSI-escaped output).
Explanation:
.γ             # Adjacent group-by on the (implicit) input-string:
               #  (implicitly push the current character)
  ð›           #  Check whether this character is larger than " "
               #  (aka, not "\t", "\n", nor " ")
 }ε            # After the group-by: map over each substring:
               #  (implicitly push the current substring)
   7Ý          #  Push a list in the range [0,7]
     39S       #  Push pair [3,9]
        δ      #  Apply double-vectorized over both lists:
         ì     #   Prepend
          ˜    #  Flatten the [[30,90],[31,93],...,[39,97]] list
           Ω   #  Pop and push a random integer from this list
   27ç         #  Push 27, and convert it to an ASCII character: ␛
      "ÿ[ÿmÿ"  #  Push this string, where:
               #   - the first `ÿ` is replaced with the ␛
               #   - the second `ÿ` is replaced with the random integer
               #   - the third `ÿ` is replaced with the current substring
             ? #  Pop and output it (without newline)


As noodle man pointed out, to check if a char's whitespace you can just check if it's <33, since we're only given printable ASCII

@emanresuA Good point, thanks. :)

this seems to work for -2 more?

@emanresuA I didn't even knew the new 05AB1E was able to compare characters.. TIL. Thanks! And by inverting the check to ð› another byte can be saved. :)

Vyxal Ḣso, 27 bytes
‛ß∵øḂ,‡ȧḃḊƛkṄ℅H`<¨² ÷¥=#Π>Π

Try it Online!
Indirect -3 thanks to l4m2 for reminding me that font tags exist, -2 thanks to lyxal, -1 thanks to pacman256. Add 3 bytes if handling HTML tags is required. See the revision history for a version with a more balanced colour distribution.
This would be a lot simpler (18 bytes) if only handling spaces was required, but oh well.
‛ß∵øḂ,              # Output "<pre>" (required because newlines)
      ‡--Ḋ          # Group adjacent items by
       ȧ            # Does removing whitespace
        ḃ           # yield an empty string?
          ƛ         # Over each
             ℅      # Choose a random integer
           kṄ       # from 1 to 4096
              H     # in hexadecimal
               `... # Compressed string "<font color=#[color]>[text]"
                    # s flag concatenates this, o flag outputs it
                    # and Ḣ flag renders the result as HTML



Try it Online! for 29 bytes using ‡ȧḃḊ

-1 using bracketify

@pacman256 Thanks, completely forgot that existed

JavaScript (ES2019), 119 bytes


f=
s=>console.log(s.replace(r=/\s*\S+\s*/g,"%c%s"),...s.match(r).flatMap(w=>['color:#'+Math.random().toFixed(3).slice(2),w]))
<input type=button value=Run onclick=f(i.value)><textarea id=i>Test&#9;of
various whitespace</textarea>



Works by logging to the browser's console which should honour tabs and newlines. Colours are random from the selection #000...#999.

108 byes

@Shaggy Needs to be able to support all printable ASCII, such as "%c" and "%s" sequences.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 83 bytes
StringReplace[a:Except[" "|"	"|"
"]..:>a~Style~RandomColor[]~ToString~StandardForm]

Try it online!
Returns a string colored in Mathematica's built-in format.


Japt, 44 40 30 bytes
Making Japt do things it shouldn't be able to do again!
OlUr"%S+"Èimi"␛[38;2;{3ÆLöÃq';

Try it (open your browser's console)

I'm only seeing greyscale in the output. Does your solution meet this part of the spec: "It should be likely that various hues and shades are represented in the result."?

I've added a broader range of colours, @Jordan, but you need to better specify that in the challenge.

Looks good. Out of curiosity, how would you specify it?

Javascript, 99 bytes


f=
s=>document.write(`<pre>`+s.replace(/\s|^|(.)/g,(h,c)=>`<font color=${z=c?z:Math.random()*1e6}>`+h))
<textarea id=input1>&lt;font color=#123456&gt; test &lt;/font&gt;</textarea><input type=button onclick=f(input1.value)>



<z>${c} to allow input with <>, later use nop <font> instead

Python 3.8 (pre-release), 113 103 bytes
from random import*
def f(s):print(''.join([c+f'\033[{randint(20,36)}m'*c.isspace()for c in' '+s])[1:])

Try it online!

103 bytes thanks @movatica for code
thanks @jdt for code and ideas and @Jordan for space remark


Does this preserve whitespace (multiple consecutive spaces, newlines, tabs) in the output?

no, i have to find another way.

This gets you closer, but you still need to color the first word. I'm also not sure if the underlined word are ok.

@jdt Your link is blocked for me could you use tio.run  , or just paste it here ?

TIO print(*[f'\033[{randint(20,36)}m{c}'if c.isspace()else c for c in t],sep='')

I think you are not compliant with Standard I/O rules, as this is a program but relying on a variable. You should either use a function or take input via stdin.

104 bytes wrapped in a function

JavaScript (Node.js), 85 70 bytes
s=>console.log(s.replace(/\S+/g,s=>`␛[38;5;${Math.random()*99|0}m`+s))

Attempt This Online!
The ␛ is used as a placeholder for what should be a raw ESC (0x1B) byte, since Stack Exchange doesn't like to render control characters.

"Output may be colored text in any environment" seems to imply that you do actually have to output the coloured text, not just create it. Also, including a literal 0x1b char saves three bytes

@emanresuA I see. Okay, I added console.log. Thanks for suggesting using the actual 0x1B byte, I used it in my Uiua solution but forgot about it here.

You might want to mention that there's a literal byte in there, since it doesn't actually render at least for me

Is this browser specific? In Chrome it applies random and multiple styles, not just colors, to consecutive groups of words.

@Shaggy It's designed to work in Node.JS (and it does), since those are ANSI colors, I don't know anything about rendering of ANSI colors in browser consoles.

Figured out that Chrome only supports RGB colours with 38;2.

Uiua, 41 38 33  30 bytes
&p⍜⊜□⍚($"\x1b[38;5;_m_"⌈×99⚂)⊸>@ 

Note the trailing space, and that \x1b should be a literal ESC byte, which is included in the SBCS encoding for Uiua, at least as of 0.13.0-dev-2.
Explanation:
⊸>@                  # mask of all characters greater than space
⍜⊜□⍚(                # apply to each island of ones:
  ⌈×99⚂              #   random integer between 1 and 99
  $"\x1b[38;5;_m_")  #   Prepend this ANSI color code to the word
&p                   # print with newline

The ANSI color codes are of the form ESC[38;5;{ID} where ID is a number between 1 and 231 inclusive which correlates to a terminal color. Here, I just used the colors 1 to 99 because it's a byte shorter and we only have to support 16 at a minimum.
Screenshot of the program running:


Perl 5 + -p, 33 bytes
s/\S+/.[38;5;@{[0|rand 256]}m$&/g
Try it online!

Typst - 117 bytes
#(a=>{show regex("\\S+"):x=>context{text(oklch(50%,99%,(here().position().x/1pt+datetime.today().day())*9deg),x)};a})

It's a function that accepts a string and returns colored content. As far as I know, the only way to have a different output each time is to use the current date.
Call it like this:
#(a=>{show regex("\\S+"):x=>context{text(oklch(50%,99%,(here().position().x/1pt+datetime.today().day())*9deg),x)};a})(
  "Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange! This is a site for recreational programming competitions, not general programming questions.
Challenges must have an objective scoring criterion, and it is highly recommeded to first post proposed challenges in the Sandbox."
)



Ruby -p, 37 bytes
Contains an unprintable ESC character before the [.
gsub(/\S+/){"[38;5;#{rand 256}m#$&"}

Attempt This Online!


C#, 136 bytes
string a()=>$"\x1B[38;5;{new Random().Next()%16}m";void f(string s){foreach(var c in a()+s)Console.Write(char.IsWhiteSpace(c)?a()+c:c);}

Try it online!
Explanation
string a()=>$"\x1B[38;5;{new Random().Next()%16}m"; // Generates a randomly colored ANSI escape color code

void f(string s)
{
    foreach(var c in a()+s) // For each char c in s, (appending a color code to the start of s)
        Console.Write(char.IsWhiteSpace(c)? a()+c : c); // If whitespace, print color code + c, else c
}




Haskell, 161, 135 bytes
import System.CPUTime
g f=f.(\(%)i->"\ESC["++shows(30+60*i%2+i%9%8)"m")mod<$>getCPUTime
f=(g(++)<*>).foldMap(g. \c i->c:[i|i<-i,c<'!'])

-26 bytes after looking at jdt's solution, and realizing that every space can have a color code attached without breaking the solution.

Try it online!

Python 3, 97 bytes
Using a lookbehind regexp to insert color codes after whitespace.
import random,re
def f(s):print(re.sub(r'^|(?<=\s)',lambda _:f'\033[{random.randint(20,36)}m',s))

Try it online!

PHP 7.4+ - 109 106 bytes
Thanks to Jordan for pointing out that the #RGB format works, and saved me 3 bytes.

An anonymous arrow function that print the HTML containing all the stylized words.
The <pre> is needed to keep the whitespace.
fn($t)=>print('<pre>'.preg_replace_callback('/\S+\s*/',fn($m)=>'<font color=#5'.rand(10,99).">$m[0]",$t))

The idea is simple: randomly generates 89 colors (the minimum required is 16), into a deprecated <font> tag.
I chose to change the green and bçue channels for a decent visual variety in the colors (1 digit for each channel).
Does it's best to keep whitespaces by using the <pre> tag.
As per the rules, HTML output is allowed, and a function is also allowed.
You can try it here:


// This is my code
let answer = "fn($t)=>print('<pre>'.preg_replace_callback('/\\S+\\s*/m',fn($m)=>'<font color=#5'.rand(10,99).\">$m[0]\",$t))";

document.getElementById('code').value = answer;
document.getElementById('code_length').textContent = answer.length;

// Here's the PHP code that will run
let code = `
// Example text
$text = "Write a program or function that takes a string as input and prints or otherwise renders the text with each word in a random color";

// My code
$fn = ${answer};

// Run the code
$fn($text);
`;

run_php(code);

async function run_php(code) {
  const { PhpWeb } = await import('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/php-wasm/PhpWeb.mjs');
  const php = new PhpWeb;
  
  let out = '';
  
  php.addEventListener('output', (event) => {
    out += event.detail.join('');
  });

  let x = await php.run('<?php ' + code);
  
  document.getElementById('output_text').value = out;
  document.getElementById('output_html').innerHTML = out;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

#code {
  width: 100vw;
  width: 100dvw;
  
  resize: resize-x;
}

#output_text {
  width: 100vw;
  width: 100dvw;
  
  height: 50vh;
  height: 50dvh;
  
  resize: resize-x;
}

#output_html {
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-width: 100dvw;
  
  overflow: auto;
}
<p>Code: - Length: <span id="code_length">0</span></p>
<textarea id="code"></textarea>
<p>Output:</p>
<textarea id="output_text"></textarea>
<div id="output_html"></div>




I think you’d get more color variety—and save 3 bytes—by using a 3-digit color code, e.g. <font color=#5'.rand(10,99).">.

@Jordan Thank you. I forgot that the #RGB format actually works, despite what the documentation says in MDN.

My answer just leave thing like one-digit there, as anyway display must have a color and therefore valid

C - 80 75 bytes
b,c;main(){while(read(1,&b,1)){c^=b;printf("␛[38;5;%dm%c",b==32?c:-1,b);}}

Try it online!
To compile locally replace ␛ with an ANSI escape (0x1b)

Ungolfed
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
char buffer,color;
int main(){
 while(read(1,&buffer,1)){ // read stdin
  color^=buffer; // make color appear random
  printf("\e[38;5;%dm%c",buffer==' ' ? color : -1, buffer);
 }
}


This seems to give the same output if run twice with the same input, which doesn't meet the spec. ("The output must have a chance of being different each time the program or function is run with the same input.")

AWK, 91 80 110 79 bytes
NR<2{srand()}{for(i=0;i++<NF;){printf"\033[38;5;"int(rand()*99)"m"$i" "}}$0=" "

Attempt This Online!
NR<2{srand()}                      # seed only once (or colors repeat)
{for(i=0;i++<NF;){printf           # print each word
"\033[38;5;"int(rand()*99)"m"$i" " # with random color
}}$0=" "                           # new line


Thank you, should be sorted, but noticeably longer.
